# How crazy should I get with turning things into objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I'm still new to OOP, and the way I initially perceived it was to throw alot of procedural looking code inside of objects, and think I'd done my job.  But as I've spent the last few weeks doing alot of thinking, reading, and coding (and looking at good code, which is a hugely under-rated resource), I believe I'm starting to grasp the different outlook.  It's really just a matter of clarity, simplicity, and organization once you get down to it.

But now I'm starting to look at things as objects that are not as black and white a slamdunk case for being an object.  For example, I have a parser, and usually the parser returns some strings that I have to deal with.  But it has one specialized case where it has to return an array, and what goes in that array and how it's formatted has specialized rules.  This only amounts to two lines plus one method of code, but this code sticks out to me as not being cleanly fitting in the Parser class, and I want to turn it into its own "ActionArray" object.

But is it going to far?  Has OOP become a hammer that is making me look at everything like a nail?  Is it possible to go too far with turning things into objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your call, *but* you should think of objects as real life objects.

Take for example a car. You could describe a car with different objects:

- Engine
- Wheels
- Chassis

Or you could describe a car with just one object:

- Engine

You can [keep it simple and stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) or you can spread the dependency to different objects.

Comment: Is a spark plug an object?  In terms of readability, is it annoying to others to see objects being objects that are very small and not 100% necessary?

Comment: The engine could have spark plugs and the spark plug could have a single method `giveSpark()`. You wouldn't give the engine a method `giveSpark()`, now would you? That's my opinion. Objects should generally just have **one** task to live for.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm not going too far at all.  The engine could calculate how often to fire the spark plug, but it shouldn't. Thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of objects in an OOP system that are not isomorphic with "real life objects". This is a leaky (if often useful) abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

As a general guideline, I think Sesame Street says it best: **you need an new object when "one of these things is not like the others"**.

Listen to your code. If it is telling you that your objects are becoming polluted with non-essential state and behavior (and thus violating the "Single Responsibility Principle"), or that one part of your object has a rate of change that is different from the rest, and so on, it is telling you that you are missing an object.

**Do the simplest thing that could possibly work**. When that no longer works, do the next simplest thing. And so on. In general, this means that **a system tends to move from fewer, larger objects to more, smaller objects**; but not always.

There are a number of great resources for OO design. In addition to the ones already mentioned, I highly recommend *Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns* and *Implementation Patterns* by Kent Beck. They use Smalltalk and Java examples, respectively, but I find the principles translate quite well to other OO languages.

Comment: I agree. *Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns* is really a misnomer. Yes, it uses Smalltalk for the examples, but it's really *Programming Best Practice Patterns*. *Implementation Patterns* is more or less the 2nd edition of *Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns*, so, again, even though it uses Java, it's really language-independent. Kent Beck's Java code ends up looking like Smalltalk with curly braces anyway, which translates quite easily into Ruby.

Comment: BTW: I vaguely recall you mentioning in a talk that you were thinking about doing a Ruby version of SBPP. Whatever became of that? Was it obsoleted by Gregory Brown's *Ruby Best Practices*?

Comment: @Jörg That project essentially stalled when I left Hashrocket. I like Greg's book though.

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns are your friend.  A class rarely exists in a vacuum.  It interacts with other classes, and the mechanisms by which your classes are coupled together is going to directly affect your ability to modify your code in the future.  With poor class design, a change that you make in one class may ripple down and force changes in other classes, which cause you to have to change other classes, etc.

Design patterns force you to think about how classes relate to each other.  For example, your Parser class might choose to implement the Strategy design pattern to abstract out the mechanism for parsing.  You might decide to create your Parser as a Template design pattern, and then have each actual instance of the Parser complete the template.

The original book on Design Patters ([Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) is excellent, but can be dense and intimidating reading if you are new to OOP.  A more accessible book (and specific to Ruby) might be [Design Patterns in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452), which has a nice introduction to design patterns, and talks about the Ruby way of implementing those patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented programming is a pretty tricky tool. Many people today are getting into the same conflict, by forgetting the fundamental OOP purpose, which is improving code maintainability.

You can always brainstorm about your future OO code **reusability** and **maintainability**, and decide yourself if it's the best way to go. Take look at this interesting study:
[Potok, Thomas; Mladen Vouk, Andy Rindos (1999). "Productivity Analysis of Object-Oriented Software Developed in a Commercial Environment"](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/~v8q/Homepage/Papers%20Old/spetep-%20printable.pdf)